# How to split up SQLAlchemy ORM and functions into two different files

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I wrote some code for an application where some information is stored in an SQLite3 database. Therefore I used SQLAlchemy and set up the object relational mapper like:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Date
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

# Setting up SQLAlchemy to connect to the local SQLite3 database
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:main:', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

The two main classes for which information is stored in the database look like this:

```
class Habit(Base):    
    __tablename__ = 'habit'
    habit_id = Column('habit_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String, unique=True)
    periodicity = Column('periodicity', String)
    start_date = Column('start_date', Date)

class HabitEvent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'habit_event'
    event_id = Column('event_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column('date', Date)
    habit_id = Column('fk_habit_id', Integer, ForeignKey(Habit.habit_id))
```

This is how my main.py should look like. Now I wrote some functions to add class objects of Habit or HabitEvent and analyize them. Here's an example:

```
def get_habits():
    """Lists all habits, including habit id, periodicity and start date."""
    
    habits = session.query(Habit).all()
    for habit in habits:
        print(str(habit.habit_id)+', '+str(habit.name) + ', ' 
              + str(habit.periodicity) +', Start Date: '
              + str(habit.start_date.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y')))
```

Now I want to seperate the functions from the ORM setup. I would like to have a main.py containing the ORM setup and the classes and an analytics.py which contains all the functions. When I do this and import the functions from the analytis.py to the main.py and try to call them, it does obviously not know the Habit and HabitEvent class, since they are not defined in the analytics.py.

Here's my final question: Is there a possibility to split the ORM and the analyzing functions up into the two suggested files? Or do they have to be part of the same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by splitting up the code into multiple files:

- main.py containing the CLI and imports all functions from analytics.py
- orm.py containing the object relational mapper setup
- classes.py containing the classes for the orm and imports Base from orm.py
- analytics.py containing all functions and imports of classes from classes.py and session from orm.py

Answer (score 0):

yes, they can be separated to multiple files.

one way of doing it is with passing session and models to the function:

```
def get_habits(session, Habit):
    """Lists all habits, including habit id, periodicity and start date."""

    habits = session.query(Habit).all()
    for habit in habits:
        print(str(habit.habit_id)+', '+str(habit.name) + ', ' 
              + str(habit.periodicity) +', Start Date: '
              + str(habit.start_date.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y')))
```

and in `main.py` file you can call this function after importing it like so:

```
get_habits(session, Habit)
```

`session` is `session = Session()` and `Habit` is the model(class) that you want to use in function.

Comment: Doing it that way, python would expect an argument for session and gives an error that no value was received.

Comment: could you show me the error message and the way that you called the function?

Comment: I changed the function the way you suggested it and I use Google's Fire CLI to call the function via the bash. I tried it with the following lines. ```python main.py get_habits``` Here I get an errorsaying: ```ERROR: The function received no value for the required argument: session``` When I use ```session``` and ```Habit``` as arguments I get the following error: 
```habits = session.query(Habit).all() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'query'``` Since python takes session as a string.